# converting a string to a date

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert a string into a sql date time value. For example 201405021843300400 should become 2014-05-02 18:43:30:400 to the milisecond.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParsePosition;

public class DateFormat {

public static String decodeDate(String myDate, String pattern) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    ParsePosition pos    = new ParsePosition(0);

    Date tmpDateTime = sdf.parse(myDate, pos);

    DateFormat dfFinal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");

    System.out.println("Milliseconds to DateTime: " + dfFinal.format(tmpDateTime));

    return dfFinal.format(tmpDateTime);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println(decodeDate("201405021843300400", "yyyyMMddhhmmssSSSS"));
}
```

}

I tried returning long, Date, java.sql.Timestamp out of decodeDate but wasn't able to do so. Is there a way to cast a string as date time stamp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you tried to return those types and weren't able to? What data type do you want to return?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't want to return a String. It should be a datetime value. (sql server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // java.sql.Date      -> java.util.Date
    // java.sql.Timestamp -> java.util.Date
    // java.sql.Time      -> java.util.Date

    // e.g. with long value

    String target = "201405021843300400";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssSSSS");

    java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(df.parse(target).getTime());

    or
    new java.sql.Timestamp(year, month, date, hour, minute, second, nano)
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked with one fix.  new java.sql.Timestamp(df.parse(target, pos).getTime())

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a prebuilt function that will do what you want, you will have to parse out the string and use the existing Calendar functions to set the various parts of the date.  It should be pretty easy to build the function, since you know your formatting.

Then you can use

```
Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
```

to create a Calendar object with the appropriate timestamp.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html